# localStorage is not working in GeckoFX 1.0.5

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, geckofx

In GeckoFX 1.0.5 web-kit localStorage is not working in C# wpf application?
Note:- GeckoFX 1.0.4 it's working.

Comment: "My car does not work today. Note: My previous car works fine". You need to say more...
What does 'not working' mean? What do you try to achieve and how?

Comment: #Bartosz I'm using GeckoFX web-kit in my wpf application for rendering HTML content.
when i'm using GeckoFX 1.0.4 we are using localStorage API to store some data and it's working fine. 
recently i'm updated GeckoFX web-kit from 1.0.4 to 1.0.5. and it's throwing a Exception "Failed to execute script." if you need more information let me know.

Comment: Can you include some code? There is quite a difference between these 2 versions...

Comment: using (AutoJSContext context = new AutoJSContext(webBrowser1.Window))
{
 try
 {
  var resul4 = context.EvaluateScript("for ( var i = 0;i<localStorage.length; i++ ) {var key = localStorage.key(i);                     if(key.indexOf(_.bookId) > -1) {localStorage.removeItem(key);i--;}}", (nsIDOMWindow)webBrowser1.Window.DomWindow);
 }
 catch (Exception ex) { }
}

Comment: You should rather edit your question put the code in there, formatted... (Ctrl+K)